# How to get CPU or memory usage of my web application?

Tags: performance, web-applications

Is there a way I programmatically get CPU and memory usage for a web app? My web application is something similar to `web.whatsapp.com`. I need to collect samples of CPU and memory usage and report it using an API. Any browser-specific commands would also work.

Answer (score -1):

Look into window.performance or window.performance.memory API calls, that is closest thing I could find.

Comment: Know of anything similar for other OS? Mac and Linux?